# BulletedList - Setting ListItem Visibility to False

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, list, visual-studio-2012

I have the following if statement:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("ModuleRole:Homework.ApproveHomework.Access")) BulletedList1.Visible = true;
    else BulletedList1.Visible = false;
```

Essentially role's are assigned to users currently logged in. BulletedList1 is simply a list of roles on the home page that users can click to do certain things, for example approve homework, delete or even add new work sheets.

In the above if statement, if the user logged in does not have access to ModuleRole:Homework.ApproveHomework.Access, the entire BulletedList will vanish. What I am wondering however is how to specifically choose which ListItem in the BulletedList I want to have a false visibility rather than the entire list being set to invisible.

Since ListItem's have no ID, can I simply do this by pointing my if statement at a specific Value?

I tried to do some searching and came up with the below code, however it isn't working:

```
BulletedList1.Items.FindByValue("Approve Calls").Visible = true;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide a single `ListItem` from a `BulletedList` in this way. You either have to use a different control (like `Repeater`, `DataList` etc.) or you could use CSS.

Try this:

```
ListItem approveItem = BulletedList1.Items.FindByValue("Approve Calls");
approveItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
// make it visible:
approveItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Remove("display");
```

If it's sufficient to disable an item you can simply use `approveItem.Enabled = false`.